# web2py check if exist in db insert or update

Tags: mysql, insert, web2py

I'm trying to perform a check to see if a record exist first before inserting the record so I won't get an error.
If it exists, i'll update a field.

```
mydb(mydb.myitems.itemNumber==int(row)).update(oldImageName=fileName) or 
mydb.myitems.insert(itemNumber=int(row),oldImageName=fileName)
```

If i try to update a record that does not exist, then it should throw a 1 or something aside from 0.  But in the case above, it always throws a 0 so the insert keeps happening.

Why is that?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Adding model:

```
mydb.define_table('myitems', 
                    Field('itemNumber', 'id',notnull=True,unique=True),
                    Field('oldImageName', 'string')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If i try to update a record that does not exist, then it should throw a 1 or something aside from 0.

If you try to update a record that does *not* exist, `.update()` will return `None`, so the insert will then happen. If matching records exist, `.update()` will return the number of records updated.

In any case, you should instead do:

```
mydb.myitems.update_or_insert(mydb.myitems.itemNumber == int(row),
                              oldImageName=filename)
```

or alternatively:

```
mydb.myitems.update_or_insert(dict(itemNumber == int(row)),
                              oldImageName=filename)
```

The first argument to `update_or_insert` is `_key`, which can either be a DAL query or a dictionary with field names as keys.

Comment: When i try to do this, it adds the first one but with itemNumber being 0.  I changed it so that mydb.myitems.id==int(row) as well but the same thing happens.  It seems to always add the itemNumber as 0 when trying to insert.

Comment: Must be a problem with the value of `row`. Would need to see the code that generates it to figure out the problem.

Comment: I've tested it and the value of row comes up fine. It seems like it has to do if i set itemNumber as primary key.  But if i set lets say "newNum" as primary key with auto increment and i only enter values into "itemNumber" that is no longer primary key then it will work.

Comment: IntegrityError: (1062, u"Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'")

Comment: Yes, you cannot insert your own values into the id field of the table, as it is an auto-incrementing field that will generate it's own values. Just make itemNumber an "integer" field (with a unique constraint). web2py will automatically add an id field as well.

Comment: Thanks as always Anthony!

Comment: I see where the problem is now.  In MySQL, itemNumber is a bigint(20).
While in web2py, i was passing the "int(row)" to it which forces it to end up as "0".  So when i removed int and passed as "row" it still takes it as 0.  How should I define itemNumber in table?

Comment: i did: bigint_id = True and also Field('itemNumber', 'bigint',notnull=True,unique=True),

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a correction of Anthony's answer which did not give quite the desired result when I tried it. If you do:

```
mydb.myitems.update_or_insert(mydb.myitems.itemNumber == int(row),
                          itemNumber = int(row),
                          oldImageName=filename)
```

then the code should insert a record with the itemNumber and filename if there is not an item with that number there already, otherwise update it.

If you miss the itemNumber = int(row), bit then web2py makes up an itemNumber which is probably not what is wanted.

See http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#update_or_insert